# Bond Futures: PnL Mismatch between underlying treasury yield delta and futures prices at close&open

Tags: bond-futures

I've traded the "US 2YR NOTE (CBT) Jun23"- Future TUM3:

- On 15-03-2023 I bought 70 contracts at 103,67829.
- On 30-05-2023 I closed the position at 101,97266.

The CTD was back then: T 0 ¼ 06/30/25.

When I check the EOD yields for the treasury note I see:

- On 15-03-2023 a yield of: 3,93 %
- On 30-05-2023 a yield of: 4,62 %

So the yield went 68bp up between open and close.

Based on the traded future prices my PnL is ~ -239k USD.
Based on the yield difference of 68bp my loss should be lower at ~ -184k (based on the total basis point value of average 2.700 USD)

Where does the difference come from?

Comment: For one thing 76bps is a fairly large move, I don't think you can expect the "2380 USD per bp" rule of thumb to hold throughout this range. The first bip was 2380, the next one a slightly different figure, and so on. It is not constant. Your second calculation can only be seen as a rough approximation.

Comment: You also have a rolldown effect on the CTD which will go against you.

Comment: @nbbo2 even taking convexity into account: BPV was in the beginning at around 2,8k and at the end around 2,5K

Comment: @oronimbus as I am long in the futures and the CTD basket bonds are trading with a huge (8pts) discount to par I should benefit from the "roll down" effect.